# Where can I find Dockerfiles for official images on Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

I would like to know how images that I use created. But more often than not it is hard task to find source of image that is published on Docker Hub if its source is not linked in description.

As far as I understand "*Dockerfiles*" in tags are not *Dockerfiles*. It is history of creation of image from source *Dockerfile*. And they have bad formatting and some information is missing (e.g. first `ADD` is usually some kind of hash of a file).

I could find for example both official Dockerfiles for MariaDB (from docker https://github.com/docker-library itself and from mariadb https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-server-docker) but I can't locate where Ubuntu image *Dockerfile* is.
Do I miss something obvious?

Comment: You don't, there is no way to find the original source Dockerfile unless they leave a link ( you can inspect docker image with tools like `dive` though).

Comment: Thanks, somehow I'm not surprised. More often than not I feel like killing one or two docker programmers. Their documentation on docker overall is probably worst of all open sourced projects. Just ugh.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think this is totally true

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε prove it: here is my image https://hub.docker.com/r/wialus/data-stripper Imagine there is no link to the github repository and that I did not use trusted builds. Now restore the complete dockerfile + other auxiliary files used to build the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually find them back this way:

1. Head to the folder *library* of the official-images repository: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/tree/master/library
2. Open the file corresponding to the image you are looking for, e.g., since you are mentioning it, Ubuntu: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/ubuntu
3. In this file, you will find a corresponding `GitRepo`, in this case

   > GitRepo: https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core.git

   <sup>Source: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/26a6a4b1727c891666eef5c95b62c9d1f9abb4b7/library/ubuntu#L5</sup>

   Also mind that you could find other git references after this, to point to different branches corresponding to different architecture:

   > # https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-amd64
   > amd64-GitFetch: refs/heads/dist-amd64
   > amd64-GitCommit: 7c60863f1bdc0466b648ada069d29a49107cc7be
   > # https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-arm32v7
   > arm32v7-GitFetch: refs/heads/dist-arm32v7
   > arm32v7-GitCommit: 33a9d794f4ac639f1a8f0b30cc5248224c3e10ff
   > # https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-arm64v8
   > arm64v8-GitFetch: refs/heads/dist-arm64v8
   > arm64v8-GitCommit: b33d0a34fac53d9ae72410192aec487360d5ba7e
   > # https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-i386
   > i386-GitFetch: refs/heads/dist-i386
   > i386-GitCommit: dcf19ce65af950a456d85a0b5041a9d9dca1a887
   > # https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-ppc64le
   > ppc64le-GitFetch: refs/heads/dist-ppc64le
   > ppc64le-GitCommit: 6f96f236699fd5f0bed4407a99f85809f04b5608
   > # https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-s390x
   > s390x-GitFetch: refs/heads/dist-s390x
   > s390x-GitCommit: 7159082e2e33ec2733200feaac06107b4d2517be

   <sup>*Source: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/26a6a4b1727c891666eef5c95b62c9d1f9abb4b7/library/ubuntu#L7*</sup>

   Where you can see that you can have the exact branch and even git commit corresponding to the actual image you will be able to pull out of Docker Hub.
4. If we take one of those branches, we see all the folders with the Ubuntu version, and if we go in one specific version folder, there we have a *Dockerfile*

   - https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/dist-amd64/xenial
   - https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/dist-amd64/xenial/Dockerfile

Just for the sake of it, let's redo this for the other one you are mentioning, mariadb:

1. https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/
2. https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/mariadb
3. https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/mariadb#L5
4. https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb

   - https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/tree/master/10.1
   - https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.1/Dockerfile

Comment: man, that's cool. I probably glanced over this file couple times in my search and did not think this comments actually lead to the source of Dockerfile of image with 1B+ pulls. Thanks. If only there was some technology do display link to the source in more convenient way.

Comment: This works **ONLY** for the official images.

Comment: @zerkms it works for all automated build images, official images are some of them. But you can configure the same in your Docker Hub account if you select automated builds. Those images are actually flagged accordingly in the Hub search page.

Comment: Related article: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/

Comment: And when I say « it works » I mean, there is a way to find the Dockerfile back.

Comment: "there is a way to find the Dockerfile back" --- if only it's official or trusted (automated) build. Those are minorities. I think the OP asked _in general_. And _in general_ it's _not possible_.

Comment: @zerkms then, I get why you answered no, in first intention. The OP was specifically speaking about official image: it is in the title of the question as well as in the fact that the two images mentioned are official images (ubuntu, mariadb).